# Is there a bitly for email?

Tags: api, email

I want the ability to use an api to input an email address such as abc@gmail.com get back a cloaked email address such as xyz@cloaked.com (preferably with cloaked.com being our own domain) and finally getting stats on emails sent to the cloaked address.

Answer (score 0):

if you want it on your own domain that maes it easier.  set up an MX record and your own mailserver, and then use the mail servers API to set up whatever random looking addresses you want.

Some malservers (eg exim) can be configured to look in an SQL database to do the lookups for forwarding the mail, I'm not aware of any standardised API for requesting or configuring forwarders, the closest to a standard I've seen is /etc/aliases